# Android Tabbed Layout is Scrollable?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I'm developing an activity with Tabbed Layout consisting of 2 fragment layout. The first fragment consisted of Listview and an EditText.
The problem with my ui is my TabbedLayout is scrollable. I mean when I try to scroll on the toolbar , it's scrollable. How to prevent it to be scrollable, because some of my Listview items is hidden below because my TabbedLayout is scrollable

[image: Before Scrolling my TabbedLayout AppBar]

[image: After Scrolled]

Comment: Can you post some design/animation to show the behaviour .

Comment: I've updated my questions

Comment: Are you using `CoordinatorLayout`  with `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: Yes , I'm using the template generated by Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define following property in your Toolbar xml :

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
```

And if you have defined following property in your frame layout then remove it .

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```